# x64_mingw not a valid platform - Rails 5

Tags: ruby, xming, gem, rails

Bluehost Shared Server 

ruby -v 2.2.2

rails -v 5.0.0.1

gem -v 2.4.5

**~/.bashrc**

```
export HPATH=$HOME
export GEM_HOME=$HPATH/ruby/gems
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3
export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
export PATH=$HPATH/ruby/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HPATH/ruby/gems/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HPATH/ruby/gems:$PATH
```

Clean Install, but when creating new app it throws an "**invalid platform**" error.

```
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
         run  bundle install
`x64_mingw` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :ruby_20, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19,
:mri_20, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19, :mingw_20]
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
`x64_mingw` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :ruby_20, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19,
:mri_20, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19, :mingw_20]
```

**Gemfile**

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Would that mean **only** comment out gem "tzinfo-data", or are other changes required as well?